# MySQL InnoDB volunteer transaction to be deadlock victim

Tags: mysql, innodb, deadlock

Is there a mechanism in MySQL (5.6 or later) to have a transaction (or statement) to volunteer to be a victim in the case it is involved in a deadlock?

---

With InnoDB deadlock detection on, when a deadlock is identified, InnoDB determines which transaction to kill (to be the victim) in order to allow the other transaction(s) to proceed. There's an algorithm used to determine which transaction is the victim.

My question is whether there is any syntax that we can use in a statement that will influence the algorithm, that basically tells InnoDB "if this statement/transaction is involved in a deadlock, then pick me as the victim."

Comment: Sounds like a good "feature request" to submit at bugs.mysql.com

Comment: MySQL Reference says `innodb_lock_wait_timeout` doesn't apply to deadlocks when `dead_lock_detect` is enabled... so that means setting this lower for a session wouldn't be an effective mechanism. (?)

Comment: There are two types of conflict.  (1) There is definitely a "deadlock", and the only sane resolution is to kill one transaction.  This is quickly discovered.  (2) Or... One of connections will release locks _eventually_, so the the other can simply wait.  In (2), if the wait is shorter than lock_wait_timeout, both transactions end nicely, though one is delayed.  If longer, then one gets a timeout error, and should be handled like a deadlock.  The flag turns a deadlock into a delay; the _hope_ is that the savings of deadlock detection is worth the delay.

Comment: That is, when a deadlock is detected (1), one of the transactions is immediately aborted; no timeout applies.  The flag turns off the "detection of deadlocks".  It is a very new (and somewhat dubious) feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "It is a far, far better thing I do..." — TRX #8675309

The current algorithm for which transaction is killed in case of a deadlock is that the transaction that has changed fewer rows is killed. In case of a tie, the choice is made arbitrarily by InnoDB internal code; we do not know the reason for the choice.

So the only way one transaction can "volunteer" is to change fewer rows than the other transaction.

Comment: Got it, thank you. +10.  But how did you get my password, Tommy TuTone?

Comment: I got your number on the wall.

Comment: "It was the best of times, it was the worst of times."

Comment: 8675309 and 6060842 are the random-looking numbers I use in most of my code examples. It's fun to see how many people are old enough to recognize them.