# MariaDB permanent variable setting

Tags: variables, mariadb

I want to set up new value for `innodb_lock_wait_timeout` variable.

I am using command:
`SET GLOBAL innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 120;`  (previous value has been 50)
DB: MariaDB

But at another day, the value returned (restarted) on 50 again (by server or I do noit know how...).

Question:
How can I set innodb_lock_wait_timeout permanently?

Comment: Even 50 is ridiculously high.  May I suggest that we discuss your transaction that is taking so long.  There are _probably_ things that can be done to get it to be well under 50 seconds.

Comment: I agree, but it is in milliseconds, and we have more then 10000 requests per minute and many transactions.

Comment: No, it is 50 seconds.  [_Reference_](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_lock_wait_timeout).  167 queries/second is modest.

Comment: For more discussion of timeout vs deadlock, read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47758614/mysql-innodb-volunteer-transaction-to-be-deadlock-victim, including the Comments.

Answer (score 0):

set it in the configuration file.

probably in my.cnf

Answer (score -1):

The `SET GLOBAL` command changes the value at runtime only, which will revert to the default value when the database is stopped and restarted.

To change the database to always use your new value, set it in the appropriate option file (probably data\my.ini) and restart the database server:

```
innodb_lock_wait_timeout=120
```